# My function is not loading in the right way

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

When I load my page my `datacollection` is null or undefined, but I want my data from the api to be filled in as soon as the site loads.

```
<script>
  import LineChart from './LineChart.js'
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    name: 'Graph',
    components: {
      LineChart
    },
    data () {
      return {
        ratingOne: null,
        ratingTwo: null,
        ratingThree: null,
        datacollection: null
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      console.log(this.datacollection)
      this.fillData()
    },
    mounted () {
    },
    methods: {
      getZeroes () {
        axios.get('MYAPI').then(response => {
          this.ratingOne = response.data.Rates.filter(rates => 
rates.rate === 0).length
          return this.ratingOne
         })
      },
      fillData () {
        this.getOnes()
        console.log(this.getZeroes())
        this.getOnes()
        this.getTwos()
         this.datacollection = {
          labels: ['Dårlig oplevelse', 'Okay oplevelse', 'Rigtig god 
oplevelse'],
          datasets: [
            {
             backgroundColor: ['#FF0000', '#D3D3D3', '#00CC00'],
              data: [this.ratingOne, this.ratingTwo, this.ratingThree]
            }
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When i use a click function it works and it loads my graph with the data I want, but it does not work when my page I loaded. Can anyone tell me why?

When i console log "this.getZeroes())" it just tells me "undefined" 
and when i click my button with update

```
<button @click="fillData()">Randomize</button>
```

it works

Comment: The `this.getZeros()` will return undefined because you are not returning anything from the function. you should add `return axios..` if you want to see the resolved promise other than undefined

Comment: Can you see the network panel if the API call is happening on page load or not?

Comment: What so you see in your page, if you output {{ratingOne}} ?

Comment: console.log(this.getZeroes()) does not work, as a) you don't return anything, and b) the response is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getZeroes, getOnes, getTwos are asynchronous functions. After getZeroes function and such are run, the data is not ready. That's why dataCollection doesn't have the right data.

You need to you promise to wait for the response finish, and update the data to the chart.

**getZeroes** will return a **promise**.

```
getZeroes () {
    return axios.get('MYAPI').then(response => {
      this.ratingOne = response.data.Rates.filter(rates => rates.rate === 0).length
      return this.ratingOne
     })
  },
```

in the **fillData**. We must wait them to finish by using **then**

```
fillData () {
    this.getOnes()
        .then(() => this.getZeroes())
        .then(() => this.getTwos())
        .then(() => {
           this.datacollection = {
              labels: ['Dårlig oplevelse', 'Okay oplevelse', 'Rigtig god oplevelse'],
              datasets: [
                 {
                     backgroundColor: ['#FF0000', '#D3D3D3', '#00CC00'],
                     data: [this.ratingOne, this.ratingTwo, this.ratingThree]
                 }
              ]
           }
        })
  }
```

Or we can even run the gets parallel and get data at once by **using Promise.all**

```
Promise.all([this.getOnes(), this.getTwos(), this,getThrees()])
    .then(() => { /* the rest here */ })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
now do i get an promise value, how do i use the result of this value within my code? 

    getZeroes () {
        return axios.get('https://beautycosapi.herokuapp.com/rate').then(response => {
          return response.data.Rates.filter(rates => rates.rate === 0).length
        })

Comment: you can try this.getZeroes().then((value) => { console.log(value) })

Comment: It gives the right value, where can i then use this value?

Comment: data: [this.getZeroes().then((value)), this.getOnes().then((value)), this.getTwos().then((value))] 

should i do somtheing like this? ^

Comment: Promise.all([this.getOnes(), this.getTwos(), this,getThrees()])
    .then(([value1, value2, value3]) => { /* the rest here. you can use those values to set anything here */ })

Comment: `fillData () {
        Promise.all([this.getZeroes(), this.getOnes(), this.getTwos()]).then(([value1, value2, value3]) => {
          this.datacollection = {
            labels: ['Dårlig oplevelse', 'Okay oplevelse', 'Rigtig god oplevelse'],
            datasets: [
              {
                backgroundColor: ['#FF0000', '#D3D3D3', '#00CC00'],
                data: [value1, value2, value3]
              }
            ]
          }
        })
      }`

now it only gives me the value1

Comment: value2 and value3 remains undefined.

Comment: It because u don't return data on getOne and getTwo. please check ur function again.

Comment: Oops forgot to change my other methods. it works now !! THanks a lot!!